# Miller-Rabin for large integers in C

Tags: c

The Miller-Rabin test could be described in pseudocode as follows:

```
Let int n be a possible prime . Let int t be a security parameter .   
Write n-1 = 2^{s} * r for odd r .
    For i = 1 to t do
       Generate a random a in [2; n-2]. Let b=a^{r} mod n .
       If b!=1 and b!=-1 do
          j=1
          While j<=s-1 and b!=-1 do
             Let b=b^{2} mod n
             If b=1 return "composite"
             j=j+1
          If b!=-1 return "composite"
    Return "prime"
```

The problem is the line let b=a^{r} mod n. If we take a 512bit integer for n, then r can easily be almost as long. Performing such an amount of exponentiations takes a long time, even though I am working with my large integers in base 2 exclusively and employ modular exponentiation by squaring (square the result and multiply the result with the base if exponent bit is 1, while iterating over all exponent bits).

Is there a way to speed up the modular exponentiation for large exponents?

Comment: usually, assembly would be used for the mod-exp step

Comment: Depending on your purposes, the best optimization might be to use a small `t`: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper88.pdf . If you are trying to vet a randomly generated 512 bit odd number `t = 2` is more than adequate.